# sql join problem

Tags: php, sql, join

I want to select all posts that contain a specific tag. I'm trying it with this query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) taglist
FROM posts p
JOIN posts_tags pt ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
WHERE (p.post_private = 0) AND t.tag_name = 'php'
GROUP BY p.post_id
```

Problem is, the query above, selects all the posts that contain the `php` tag, but doesn't select any of the other tags a post may contain. Without the `AND t.tag_name = 'php'` part, it does select every tag a post has, but I want to be able to filter by tag...

Any ideas how to do this? I've tried many things, but can't figure it out...

Sample data without the `AND` statement:

```
|| *taglist* ||
|| php,echo  ||
|| c++, cout ||
```

Sample data with the `AND` statement:

```
|| *taglist* ||
|| php       ||
```

What I want:

```
|| *taglist* ||
|| php,echo  ||
```

(the posts that contain the PHP tag only)

Comment: RIGHT JOIN? Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: You're right, I don't need that one here, but still not working though

Comment: Can you provide sample data and what your expected output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) taglist
    FROM posts p
        /* These 2 joins get the list of all tags */
        INNER JOIN posts_tags pt
            ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
        INNER JOIN tags t
            ON pt.tag_id = t.tag_id
        /* These 2 joins guarantee the 'php' tag is included */
        INNER JOIN posts_tags pt2
            ON p.post_id = pt2.post_id
        INNER JOIN tags t2
            ON pt2.tag_id = t2.tag_id
                AND t2.tag_name = 'php'
    WHERE p.post_private = 0
    GROUP BY p.post_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I would have found that. Still don't really understand how the bottom two joins work..

Comment: @Sled: The bottom two joins are the same as the first two except that they also include the criteria `AND t2.tag_name = 'php'`. Because they're INNER joins, they guarantee that any post returned must have the php tag associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain why your first try does not work.

What you really trying to do is to find all posts that **one** of their tags is 'php'.
But their tags are spread in **many rows** so the `t.tag_name = 'php'` does not work as it filters out all rows that don't have the 'php' tag.

When you want to check a condition that depends on many rows,

you either create a subquery (to find all post_ids that do have php tag)

```
  p.post_id IN
  ( SELECT pt2.post_id
      FROM post_tags pt2 
        JOIN tags t2
          ON t2.tag_id = pt2.tag_id
      WHERE t2.tag_name = 'php'
  )
```

but still join these post_ids with all related tags.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) taglist
  FROM posts p
    JOIN posts_tags pt
      ON p.post_id = pt.post_id
    JOIN tags t
      ON t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
  WHERE (p.post_private = 0) 
    AND p.post_id IN
      ( SELECT pt2.post_id
          FROM post_tags pt2 
            JOIN tags t2
              ON t2.tag_id = pt2.tag_id
          WHERE t2.tag_name = 'php'
      )
  GROUP BY p.post_id
```

Or you do it a bit more cleverly as Stefanelli showed with 2 more JOINs (that act similarly to a subquery)